# The text file specification does not exist when importing into Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to import a semi colon delimited `.csv` file into an access database using the following code. I've set up an import specification which works called "Import-FACTS". and VBA can see the specification (by putting `OLEacc.CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(0)` into the watch window.

```
Sub ImportFacts()

Dim OLEacc As Access.Application

Set OLEacc = GetObject("", "Access.Application")

OLEacc.OpenCurrentDatabase (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "LargeData.accdb")

OLEacc.DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _ 
   SpecificationName:="Import-FACTS",_
   TableName:="Facts",_
   Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Facts.csv",_
   HasFieldNames:=False

End Sub
```

However I get the debug message:

> Run-time error '3625' The text file specification "Import-Facts" does
>   not exist You cannot import export or link using the specification.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library

Comment: `ImportExportSpecifications` are saved jobs.  `SpecificationName` is something else.  What happens if you open an Access session (without Excel) and attempt the same `TransferText` ... replacing `ThisWorkbook.Path` with the path to the folder which contains the CSV file?

Comment: @HansUp It returns the same error message. as suggested I used: `DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, SpecificationName:="Import-FACTS", TableName:="Facts", FileName:="C:\***\Facts.csv", HasFieldNames:=False`. Do you know how I create an import specification rather than a saved job? I hadn't realised there was a difference.

Comment: @HansUp I've managed it! Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction! There's a way of saving import specifications in the Advanced options of the import wizard.

Answer (score 8):

**Important note for imports**

There is a problem with the text file specification as the name may not be the same that is displayed when you check your saved imports.

To know the true name, run the following SQL:

```
SELECT MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, 
       MSysIMEXColumns.FieldName, 
       MSysIMEXColumns.Start, 
       MSysIMEXColumns.Width, 
       MSysIMEXColumns.SkipColumn

FROM MSysIMEXColumns INNER JOIN 
     MSysIMEXSpecs ON MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID = MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecID

ORDER BY MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, 
         MSysIMEXColumns.Start, 
         MSysIMEXColumns.Width;
```

The `SpecName` field contains the right name you are looking for!

Comment: Cheers! I'll give it a go!

Comment: This deserves way more up votes, I searched all over trying to solve the issue explained here